# show that $b_1 + b_2 +...+b_n \geq a_1 + a_2 + ...+a_n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a_1,..,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ are positive real numbers satisfying $$a_1 \geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n\quad \&\quad b_1 \geq b_2 \geq ... \geq b_n$$ and $$b_1b_2..b_k \geq a_1a_2..a_k$$
for all $1 \leq k \leq n$. show that $$b_1 + b_2 +...+b_n \geq a_1 + a_2 + ...+a_n$$. 
I tried to write $b_n \geq \frac{a_{n-1}...a_1}{b_{n-1}...b_1}a_n$,then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: the question write it that way. It says that the two sequence of number is non increasing.

Comment: this is a standard example of Karamata's inequality. Write $b_i = e^{x_i}, a_i = e^{y_i}$ and show that $x_i$ and $y_i$s satisfy the Karamata condition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use this to solve the problem